# Restrict variadic function template to only accept variations of one variadic class template's nested variadic class template?

Tags: c++, templates, function, c++11, variadic

I have a variadic class template that has a nested variadic class template.  The outer class template has a function template that accepts any number of arguments and will return an object of type inner.  My problem is creating a completely separate function that will accept any number of any variation of those inner types (and only the inner types), regardless of the variant of the outer type, while still ensuring that accepted types to the function are nested members of only that outer class template.  Not sure if I explained that adequately...  Here's essentially what I'm working with:

```
template<typename... ArgsOuter> class Outer {
    typedef Outer<ArgsOuter...> outer_t;

    template<typename... ArgsInner> class Inner {
        //static const outer_t* outer;
        typedef outer_t outer;

        Inner(const ArgsInner&... args_inner) {
            //do stuff
        }
    };

    /*
      What's passed in here will be related to and will be a subset of
      the types used to define the Outer class, but I'm not really
      concerned about checking what's being passed in right now.
    */
    template<typename... ArgsFunc>
    make_inner(ArgsFunc... args_func) {
        return Inner<ArgsFunc...> (args_func...);
    }
};

struct ThingA : Outer<int, int, float> {
};

struct ThingB : Outer<int, string, int> {
};

struct ThingC : Outer<string, string, int, int> {
};

//struct ThingN : Outer<random types...> {}

//...meanwhile, over at main...

ThingA tA;
ThingB tB;
ThingC tC;

auto tA_inner = tA.make_inner(1, 1.1);
auto tB_inner = tB.make_inner(2, "foo");
auto tC_inner = tC.make_inner("bar", 2, "foobar");

//mystery_func() is the function I'm not sure how to define.
auto meatloaf = mystery_func(tA_inner, tB_inner, tC_inner);
```

Anyone have an SFINAE or variadic function template (or other) solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I didn't set out to answer my own question, but I think I've beat my head against the wall just enough the past few days to figure this one out... and certainly learned some new stuff along the way (no complaints there).  It's a bit of an ugly duckling (SFINAE + type traits metafunctions + variadic function templates), but I've run a few simple test and it seems to work as expected.

```
//Use SFINAE to limit the types accepted
template<typename A, typename Result>
struct require_1_type { };

//Limit to Outer class
template<typename... ArgsA, typename Result>
struct require_1_type<Outer<ArgsA...>, Result> {
    typedef Result type;
};

//Zero argument, base case for variadic function template.
void mystery_func() {}

//Recursive portion of variadic function template.
template<template<typename...> class First, typename... ArgsA, typename... Others>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<
        First<ArgsA...>
        , typename require_1_type<
            typename First<ArgsA...>::outer_t
            , typename First<ArgsA...>::outer_t::template Inner<ArgsA...>
        >::type
    >::value
    , some_lib::list<First<ArgsA...>, Others...>
>::type
mystery_func (First<ArgsA...> first, Others... others) {
    mystery_func(others...);
    return some_lib::make_list(first, others...);
}
```

My goal was to limit the types being passed in, to any variations of Inner for any variations of Outer.  I think this does what I was looking for, at least it seems that way.

My understanding of how this all works is as follows, please correct as appropriate:

A series of `Inner` objects gets passed in.  Each `Inner` object has a typedef referring to its' `Outer` type.  We strip off one `Inner` object from the parameter pack, and check the typedef referring to its' `Outer` type to make sure it matches the expected `Outer` type.  If it matches, then we take the parameter pack used on the first `Inner` object that was passed in, and pass the pack along to an `Inner` template that we reference through the `Outer` typedef referred to by the first `Inner`.  Then we check those two `Inner`'s against each other to make sure they're the same.  If they are, then that particular function template instantiation is enabled.

The variadic function template itself simply calls itself recursively so that all objects in the parameter pack have those same checks run on them, until we run out of arguments, which calls the blank version of the function.  Finally, each recursion makes a call to (in this case) a function that puts the objects together in a list.

One thing I'm not sure of is if the compiler is optimizing out all those calls to make_list that are returning into nothingness, except the last one, which is done by the first invocation of `mystery_func()`, and the only one that has a purposeful return value.

Anyway, improvements, comments, and simplifications are most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might actually be impossible.  What you seem to want is the ability to do something like so:

```
template < typename ... Args1, typename ... Args2, typename ... Args3>
?? mystery_func(Inner<Args1...>,Inner<Args2...>,Inner<Args3...>);
```

I don't think you can do that.  If you can, then there's your answer.

Since I doubt you can do that, what you'll have to do instead is just take three different types and then use SFINAE to test that they are Inner<>s, which would be as easy as using a basic is_a metafunction:

```
template < typename T > is_inner : boost::mpl::false_ {};
template < typename ... Pack > is_inner< Inner<Pack...> > : boost::mpl::true_ {};
```

Comment: Well, I'm thinking that if I can isolate just one instance of Outer and Inner together, then a variadic function template could handle what I want to do, but I don't have much experience with building those (simple ones, sure, but not like this lol).  On the other hand, I know SFINAE can handle a set number of arguments to mystery_func, but I'm at a loss for how to set it up for N arguments.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't possibly do it the first way.  The second way is easy, just accept a pack of Args and make sure that is_inner is true for all of them.

Comment: I spent a few days digging into this further and I think I have a solution.  I've posted an answer showing what I did.  I honestly didn't set out to just answer my own question, so I don't mean anything by changing my accepted answer.  I've upvoted your answer since it got me thinking in the right direction (or what I think was the right direction, my solution could just be junk, but it seems to work.)  Anyway, feel free to poke holes and critique :)